# Lambda invoke wrong lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, invoke

I am invoking lambda functions based on swtich case with post request but its not working correctly.
Below are the steps.
1) Post request for first lambda invoke first lambda function.
2) Post request for second lambda invoke first lambda function again.
3) Post request for second lambda invoke second lambda function.

Please let me know if there is any issue in my code. Below is code.

```
    //Invoke lambda function dyamically based on id i.e. 1,2,3 or 4
    let invokeLambdaFunction = await getLambdaFunction(id);

    const params = 
    {
        FunctionName: invokeLambdaFunction,
        InvocationType: "Event",
        Payload: '{ "name" : '+id+' }'
    };

    try
    {
        await lambda.invoke(params).promise();

    }
    catch (ex) // if failed
    {
        console.error(ex);
    }

async function getLambdaFunction(id){
    let calledfunction= '';
    switch (id) {
      case 1:
        calledfunction= FUNCITON1;
        break;
      case 2:
        calledfunction= FUNCITON2;
        break;

    }

   return calledfunction; 
}
```

Comment: Have you tried printing `id` and the result of `getLambdaFunction` to verify they are both what you expect?

Comment: Yes its showing the correct value in cloud watch log

Comment: can you confirm that `case 1:` reflects `case <lambdaId>:`?

Comment: Yes its reflects the case <lambdaId>

Comment: can you confirm this works w/ a good ol' `if/else` Nothing seems wrong...thought you `getLambdaFunction()` doesnt need to be async

Comment: As you haven't posted the start of the code, is `let invokeLambdaFunction = await getLambdaFunction(id);` inside a (js) function? Just wondering if it's something that's only being run on lambda function startup, rather than on every invoke.

Comment: We have fixed issue by adding condition in lambda function which is calling from above code.
Thanks for your help!!